# Prove linear independence if a vector v is expressed as a unique linear combination of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to tackle this exercise:

> Prove that if a vector  is uniquely expressed as a linear combination
>   of the vectors {$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$} then this vectors are linearly
>   independent. Prove also the contrapositive.

Actually this idea came up to me when writing the question check for mistakes and contradictions please.

[They don't allow me to embed images so they've added a link,check it clicking this phrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwoCS.jpg)

If the link does not work. What I did was to write $v$ as a unique linear combination of {$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$} like this: $v=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$

Then assuming that {$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$}  are linearly dependent in search for a contradiction. $0=k_1v_1+...+k_nv_n$ where $k_1,...,k_n$ are not all equals to $0$. let's say $k_n$ different from $0$

$v_n=(k_1v_1/-k_n)+...+(k_{n-1}v_{n-1}/-k_n)$ but when we substitute this in the linear combination of $v$ is a contradiction because we have assumed that it was unique.

So {$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$}  are linearly independent.

So if this is correct I just need a hint on proving the contrapositive

Comment: There is a logical equivalence between $A \Rightarrow B$ and $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$. That seems to be the contrapositive. Alas your proof by contradiction seems to be that proof to me.

Comment: I think you have the right idea but $v_n=(c_1v_1/-k_1)+...+(c_nv_n/-k_1)$ is not correct; it should be $v_n=-(k_1v_1/k_n)-\ldots-(k_{n-1}v_{n-1}/k_n)$.  It might also help if, after you do the substitution, you show just why it leads to an expression for $v$ which is different from $v=c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n$.

Comment: @ForgotALot Your are right, however I don't know how to put the subscripts n-1 in the right way, can you fix it?

Comment: @ForgotALot Thanks btw

Comment: Just in case, if you see a formula and you want to know how it was written, click your right mouse button and select "Show Math As," then "TeX Commands."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume first that $v = \sum c_i v_i$ is the unique expression of $v$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$. Then adding $v$ to both sides of the linear dependence relation $0 = \sum a_i v_i$ yields
$$ \sum c_i v_i = v = \sum (a_i + c_i)v_i.$$

Therefore by uniqueness we must have $a_i + c_i = c_i$ for all $i$, i.e., $a_i = 0$ for all $i$. This proves linear independence.

For the converse, assume linear independence of the $v_i$ and write $v = \sum a_i v_i = \sum b_i v_i$ in any two ways. Then $0 = \sum (a_i - b_i)v_i$, so by linear independence we have $a_i - b_i = 0$ for all $i$, i.e., $a_i = b_i$. Therefore the expression of $v$ in terms of $v_i$ is unique.

Answer (score 1):

That is the approach I would take.  Assume that $v_1...v_n$ are dependent.  Then some non trivial combination = 0.  Therefore, any vector cannot be expressed as a $unique$ combination.

However, this proof really is a proof of the contrapostion.  If the vectors are not linearly independent, then there is no unique combination.

To prove it the other way...$\mathbf v$ is a unique combination of vectors $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,...\mathbf v_n$.
$\mathbf v= c_1\mathbf v_1+c_2\mathbf v_2+...c_n\mathbf v_n \iff c_1...c_n$ equal whatever it is that they equal, then there exist no $k_1...k_n$ such that $k_1\mathbf v_1+k_2\mathbf v_2+...k_n\mathbf v_n = 0$ therfore $\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,...\mathbf v_n$ are independent.